# Where can I find themes Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: configuration, system

Where can I find themes for Ubuntu 12.04 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can download `Unity Tweak Tool` from the software center.

In there you can find buttons that open a menu to change themes for Ubuntu. Also you can change icon themes there.

In case you want to download some 3rd party themes, have a look at this for example:
https://numixproject.org/store/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=53

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend mate :)

But, as a little suggestion. This is awesome theme + icon pack that i use in my laptop

http://mokaproject.com/